# Why all components will updated same value when a single component will update?

Tags: reactjs

Have a same component and it will appearing multiple times, when I changed any of one component then all components value will automatically updated. 
But I want to change the particular component value. 
So please tell me how to update a particular component value using onChange function ?

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";

 export default class ParentComponent extends Component {
     constructor(props){
         super( props);
         this.state= {
           queryPanelCounter: 3,
           fruit: 'A',
         }
     }

     handleChange = (event) => {
         this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
     }

     render(){
         let rawHtml= [];
         for(let i=0; i< this.state.queryPanelCounter; i++){
             rawHtml.push( 
                 <ReactExample name="fruit" value={this.state.fruit} 
      handleChange={this.handleChange} /> 
             );
         }

         return(
             <div>{rawHtml}</div>
         );
     }
 }

 export const ReactExample = ({ name, value, handleChange }) => (
     <select name={name} value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
         <option value="A">Apple</option>
         <option value="B">Banana</option>
         <option value="C">Cranberry</option>
     </select>
 )
```

Comment: In your <ReactExample> you should have a key that is unique, for example key={i} - you should also abstract the html construction out to a class method - you have it in the render() right now so every time it gets rendered it will reconstruct those child components.

Comment: Unrelated: `rawHtml` is a misleading name.

Comment: Hi param, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have single source of data, `fruit: 'A'`.

So whenever you change any select box, all the select box changes, because all are refering to the single state value.

One way is to have a array in state,

```
this.state= {
    queryPanelCounter: 3,
    fruits: []   //You can define initial selected as ["A","B","C"]
}
```

Then you need to pass `index` as props to child component, which will get used at the time of state updation. Also it is better if you take your `rawHtml` logic in a function outside of render to improve the performance,

```
rawHtml = () => {
    let rawHtml= [];
    for(let i=0; i< this.state.queryPanelCounter; i++){
        rawHtml.push( 
            <ReactExample name="fruit" value={this.state.fruits[i]} handleChange={this.handleChange} ind={i}/>  //Pass ind here
        );
    }
    return rawHtml
}
```

And you usage of `rawHtml` function,

```
<div>{this.rawHtml()}</div>
```

And the state update is,

```
handleChange = (event, index) => {
  let fruits  = [...this.state.fruits];
  fruits[index] = event.target.value;
    this.setState({fruits});
}
```

Finally from the child component, you need to pass the index to update state value,

```
const ReactExample = ({ name, value, handleChange, ind }) => (  //take index 
     <select name={name} value={value} onChange={(e) => handleChange(e,ind)}> //send ind to update state
         <option value="A">Apple</option>
         <option value="B">Banana</option>
         <option value="C">Cranberry</option>
     </select>
)
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gyrqsa)